# Finding out the text of span that triggered a jQuery ui tooltip

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I wrapped all the words in my page with a span tag and I have it span triggers and tool tip. I need a different ajax tool tip for each word so I need to know the contents of span. When I access `$(event.target).text` I just get the code tool tip request and not the span that triggered it.

I can write out text or request content from webpage, I just don't know how to find which span triggered it.

Thanks

Comment: `$(event.target)` is the correct reference...!

Comment: Provide relevant sample replicating issue